# Is it possible to same key with differ class and data type in data class kotlin android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have one issue about code **data class** kotlin android.

How to implement server response? sometimes I get `String` value or sometime get `Object` class.

```
class CMSRespTemp {

    data class CMSRespApi(
        val status: Boolean = false,
        val message: String = "",
        val data: String as Data
    )

    data class Data(
        val cms_id: String = "",
        val cms_content: String = ""
    )
}
```

When I implement only `Data` class it works, like this `val data: Data` or `val data: String`. But I need together `Data` and `String` with key only data.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can use `Any` type, it is equivalent to **Object** type in java.

Comment: okay, i will try and let you know and working or not ? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered to use generics for that problem?

Comment: @JeelVankhede can u post answer this one

Comment: @NajibPuthawala can you show me the scenario for which you're having String & Data type, it'll help me improve answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When having multiple type for same variable, we can use `Any` type which is equivalent to `Object` type in java. So solution is like below :

```
class CMSRespTemp {

    data class CMSRespApi(
        val status: Boolean = false,
        val message: String = "",
        var data: Any? = null // changed it to var from val, so that we can change it's type runtime if required
    )

    data class Data(
        val cms_id: String = "",
        val cms_content: String = ""
    )
}
```

And when accessing that variable, one can simply cast like below :

```
val apiResponse : CMSRespApi //= some API response here from network call
when (apiResponse.data) {
    is String -> {
        // apiResponse.data will be smart-casted to String here
    }
    else -> {
        val responseData = Gson().fromJson<CMSRespApi.Data>(
            Gson().toJsonTree(apiResponse.data),
            CMSRespApi.Data::class.java
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Data object value is not come and coming null. So how to come data ?

Comment: Can you provide your API response?

Comment: see this response :  {"status":true,"message":"OK","result":{"id":"39","name":"test sixe"},"errors":""}

Comment: if status false like this :  {"status":true,"message":"OK","result":,"No data."errors":""}

Comment: Okay.. if you use **GSON** for serialisation and deserialisation the use `@serializedName("result")` or rename **data** variable to **result**.

Comment: Also, you'll need to change your `Data` class accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190314/discussion-between-najib-puthawala-and-jeel-vankhede).

Answer (score 2):

After 12 Hrs spent and finally, got the solution for my self,

```
 val getResultCon = getSerCont.result // response Any
 val gson = Gson()
 val jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(getResultCon)
 val resultData = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, SearchContactApi.Result::class.java)
```

Convert your data string to toJsonTree and fromJson with model class then got result.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had finally solved my problem after hours of googling here and there.
  Thanks once again. You really saved me from missing my deadlines